# Typescript: Generics error while finding key based on value

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I am trying to write a utility function to return the `key` based on the `value` from a map

eg:

```js
{
  1: "python",
  2: "java",
  3: "go" // and so on 
}
```

##### expectation

```js
const key = getKeyByValue(map, "python") // key === 1
```

##### issue

But I want to use `generics` so that I can use it with `any type` of key|value in the map

#### My attempt

```js
export const getKeyByValue = <M, V>(map: M, value: V): V => {
  for (let key in map) {
    if (map[key] === value) { //  showing error 
      return key
    }
  }
}
```

#### Error message

```
This condition will always return 'false' since the types 
'M[Extract<keyof M, string>]' and 'V' have no overlap.
```

Comment: Tho is your "map" an `Map` or an `Object`?

Answer (score 0):

You have a first problem with your return type which should be type of key and not type of value. (As you want to return the key)

Another problem with the type of your map which should be `typeof Map<K, V>` (K for key, V for value)

That said the definition of your method should looks like

`export const getKeyByValue = <K, V>(map: Map<K, V>, value: V): K | undefined`

Now, not all paths return in your function. And if your map is dynamic you can always pass a non existing value. So you probably need to deal with that problem too. By returning `null`, `undefined` or throw an error depending on your needs.

```
export const getKeyByValue = <K, V>(map: Map<K, V>, value: V): K | undefined => {
    map.forEach((val, key) => {
        if (val === value) {
            return key;
        }
    });
    return undefined;
};
```

Comment: Are we able to use `.forEach` on `Map` (which, I presume is an object)? TS-playground [link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBA5gUygaQQTwEJoGoEMA2ArgjALwwA8yANDNgHwAUAtrgA4BcMAsu1bQ1oA3AsS7YAlF2QwAPjEJgAJggBmASzAIlZejADeAKBgmYrNgDpVIAE4BRXMAAWjRiPy0A1ugm6Dx00D1VRg3AjJScndiXyNA+NMbJEIbMBhvNABuAISAXxyYXIlswKSoFLTFFQ0tJWzc7KA)

Comment: Yes `Map` is an iterable object https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/forEach

Comment: @jsN00b I assumed his Object was in fact a Map which is an iterable object. But in his exemple he uses an Object which is not iterable. and in this case you are right he needs to use `Object.entries`